# google combo chart move area to the back

Tags: google-visualization, combo-chart

We have a google combo chart with 5 areas and 1 bar.[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMC8P.png)

The horizontal lines als Areas, because we needed 5 different colored lines.

But whatever we try, the area lines are displayed over the bar.
I tried to put the series in a different order. Like first the bar serie and than the area series, or reversed.

Does anyone know how you can force to put the area series to the back, so the bar is more visible?

Comment: will you please share the code used to draw the chart?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.